# Question regarding the proof of theorem 10.30 of Rudin's functional analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

[image]

I cannot understand why I can obtain a simply connected open set $\Omega$ containing $\sigma(x)$? $\sigma(x)$ is not assumed to be connected in general. Could anyone please explain?

Comment: Join $0$ and $\infty$ with a simple curve avoiding the spectrum which we can do by hypothesis; the complement of that curve is your simply connected domain $\Omega$

Comment: @Conrad Why not an official answer?